MATLAB Ocean wave simulation: problems with calibrating, getting & analyzing results
There is a task: to simulate waves on the ocean surface 3D case. The necessary laws, formulas and parameters for modeling are given (on the image). I got some results, but they are different from what should actually happen. Further correction and analysis of possible mistakes (and even correct results in general) became very difficult due to the peculiarities of the code I wrote.

Example of my code:
clear,clc
%% Data 
x = 0:1:100; % coordinates х [m]
y = 0:1:100; % coordinates y [m]
g = 9.81; % gravitational constant [m/s^2]
speed = 5; % wind velocity [m/s]
w0 = (g / speed); % norm.frequency [Hz]
dw = 0.1; % frequency step [rad/s]
w = 0.8:dw:11.1; % frequency [rad/s] 
dtt = pi / 6; % angular step [rad]
theta = -pi/2:dtt:pi/2; % direction angles, angles between the wavevector & coordintae axis [rad]

[X,Y,W,THETA] = ndgrid(x,y,w,theta);

%% P-M spectrum, Frequency-Angular spectrum & Amplitude
Psi = 8.1e-3 .* ((W/w0).^(-5)) .* exp((-0.74) ./ ((W/w0).^(4))); % P-M spectrum [none]
Phi = ((speed)^(5)/g^(3)) * Psi; % self-similar spectrum [none]
Sw = Phi / 2; % frequency spectrum [none]

wIndx = find(squeeze(Psi(1,2,:,4)) == max(max(squeeze(Psi(1,2,:,4))))); 
w_max = w(wIndx); % frequency of the peak [rad/s]
m = 1.8 * (w_max ./ W);
St = cos(THETA).^(m); % angular spectrum []
Norm = trapz(dtt, St); % norm.coefficient [none]
Swt = Sw .* St; % frequency-angular spectrum []

figure(1);
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(w, squeeze(Psi(1,2,:,4))); % squeeze(Psi(1,2,:,4)) - remove 3 dimensions x,y & theta of Psi to build a plot of Psi(w)
title('$$\Psi$$($$\omega$$) - P-M spectrum', 'Interpreter', 'LaTex');
xlabel('\omega [rad/s]');
ylabel('\Psi [none]');
grid on;
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(w, squeeze(Swt(1,2,:,:))); % squeeze(Swt(1,2,:,4)) - remove 3 dimensions x,y & theta of Swt to build a plot of Swt(w)
title('$$S(\omega , \theta)$$($$\omega$$) - frequency-angular spectrum', 'Interpreter', 'LaTex');
xlabel('\omega [rad/s]');
ylabel('S(\omega,\theta) []');
grid on;

eta0 = sqrt((Swt * dw * dtt) ./ Norm); % amplitude [m] 

%% Setting the initial phase parameter
phase = 2*pi*rand(length(w),length(theta)); % random initial phase ranging from 0 to 2pi [rad]
% For each individual harmonic (frequency) and direction angle there is its own separate random phase, but for each individual x & y it must remain constant (which is why the loop is made)
for i = 1:length(x)
    for j = 1:length(y)
    PHASE(i,j,:,:) = phase(:,:,1,1);
    end
end

%% Surface Waving [Linear, 3D (eta & x,y)] at different harmonics & random phase (at one moment in time), different directions of the wavevector (multiple angles)
t = 0; % time moment [s]
Kabs = (W.^2) / g; % wavevector module [rad/m]

eta = eta0 .* cos(W * t - Kabs .* cos(THETA) .* X - Kabs .* sin(THETA) .* Y + PHASE); % surface waving (individual harmonics) [m]
% sum(sum(eta,4),3) - double sum of eta over all harmonics (frequencies) and wavevector directions (angles theta),
% where '3' и '4' summation indicator for variable frequency and angle
etaS = sum(sum(eta,4),3); 
    
figure(2)
surf(x,y,squeeze(eta(:,:,3))); % squeeze(eta(:,:,3)) - remove the extra frequency dimension of eta to build a plot eta(x,y)
title('\eta(x,y) - one of the harmonics \omega = 0,8 : 11,1 rad/s');
xlabel('x [m]');
ylabel('y [m]');
zlabel('\eta [m]');
grid on

figure(3)
surf(x,y,etaS);
title('\eta(x,y) - surface waving');
subtitle('$$\eta(x,y) = \sum_{i=\omega}\sum_{j=\theta} {\eta_{0}}_{i,j}\cos({\omega}_{i}t - {|\vec{k}|}_{i}\cos({\theta}_{j})x - {|\vec{k}|}_{i}\sin({\theta}_{j})y + {\varphi}_{ij})$$', 'Interpreter','LaTex');
xlabel('x [m]');
ylabel('y [m]');
zlabel('\eta [m]');
cbar = colorbar;
cbar.Label.String = '\eta [m]';
grid on

As you can see I resorted to using ndgrid and got 4D data arrays. A very suboptimal approach, in which I cannot properly see what it calculated for me in the matrix. And also I can't increase the coordinate array to 1 kilometer with one meter step (make x = 0:1:1000; y = 0:1:1000;), because my PC simply does not have enough memory for this.
Specific example:
Based on the calculation results, I received the following plots:
This model has disadvantages, such as small amplitudes (they should be bigger) and absence of a general direction of the waves. Since I have 4D arrays I can't properly view where there might be a flaw in the calculations (I can't even open them becaause of the 4D size). I've tried going to loops, but with no success. I still have to deal with 4D arrays. I have kept this approach for random phase calculations and it is also inconvenient.
%% Setting the initial phase parameter
phase = 2*pi*rand(length(w),length(theta)); % random initial phase ranging from 0 to 2pi [rad]
% For each individual harmonic (frequency) and direction angle there is its own separate random phase, but for each individual x & y it must remain constant (which is why the cycle is made)
for i = 1:length(x)
    for j = 1:length(y)
    PHASE(i,j,:,:) = phase(:,:,1,1);
    end
end


While searching for a solution to my problem, I came across this post: Matlab/CUDA: ocean wave simulation
I found it very interesting and promising for solving my questions. Moreover, the idea of using GUI to make animated simulation of the waves on the ocean surface (and not just produce "dry" and static surfaces), for ability to experiment with parameters such as change frequencies (or wavelengths), directions of the waves (angle range), frequency and angular steps, wind velocity and etc., is very attractive.
But since I'm having trouble with fixing all this math underlying my simulation and I'm new to MATLAB (or any other language), I haven't been able to figure out my problem.
How to make my code more optimal and more usable?
